# Conditional Formatting a Range based on Text from Range on separate Sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filtering, string-comparison, text-comparison

Populating a dynamic event calendar from a separate sheet and want the titles of each event to be bold font.

Conditional formatting works if I am comparing to a single string or cell with text, but there are multiple titles that would appear in each column.

Need to use "Text is exactly" or a custom formula, where if any of the cells in column D for example match any of the titles from column E of another sheet, make them bold.

A separate sheet can only be accessed via the "INDIRECT" function, but even when I pull the list of titles onto the same sheet, it does not work.

Have tried the built in "Text is exactly", also tried custom formulas using TEXT, EXACT, IF, etc. but can't seem to get it to work.

Tried custom formula:
=$E$8:$E$52=TEXT($E$55,$E$56) This only matches the first instance (E8 to E55)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format range `E8:E52` with this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule:

`=match(E8, E$55:E$56, 0)`

To get the titles from the other sheet, use something like this:

`=match(E8, indirect("Sheet2!A2:A"), 0)`